# What is the point of the Map.Entry parameter to LinkedHashMap#removeEldestEntry?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry-java.util.Map.Entry-) describes this method using the following example:

```
private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 100;

protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
   return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
}
```

In this example, the method does not use the parameter, `eldest`. What is the point of this parameter to `LinkedHashMap#removeEldestEntry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you quote is just an example of how to override that method.
The actual implementation is:

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
    return false;
}
```

It is meant to be overridden, and some implementations can examine the eldest entry to decide whether or not it should be removed.